# zod definition is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer?

Tags: typescript, zod

I have a recursive type in zod like this (the ending `LoadFindRoll`):

```
import { z } from 'zod'

const LoadFindLikeLinkBond = z.object({
  link: z.string(),
})

const LoadFindLikeBond = z.union([
  z.string(),
  z.boolean(),
  z.null(),
  z.number(),
])

const LoadFindLike = z.object({
  base: LoadFindLikeLinkBond,
  form: z.enum(['like']),
  head: z.union([LoadFindLikeLinkBond, LoadFindLikeBond]),
})

const LoadFindRoll = z.object({
  form: z.enum(["roll"]),
  list: z.lazy(() => z.array(LoadFindLink)),
});

const LoadFindLink = z.lazy(() => z.union([LoadFindLike, LoadFindRoll]));
```

However, on the last two types, I am getting this error:

> `'LoadFindLink'` implicitly has type `'any'` because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.ts(7022)
> `const LoadFindLink: any`

How do I properly type this in zod? Basically I want to have a type like the [recursive type example](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#recursive-types), but I'm not sure how to apply it to my situation.

My full module code is actually quite intertwined:

```
import { z } from 'zod'

export const Load = z.object({
  find: z.optional(z.lazy(() => LoadFind)),
  read: z.optional(z.lazy(() => LoadRead)),
  save: z.optional(z.lazy(() => LoadSave)),
  task: z.optional(z.string()),
})

export const LoadFind = z.union([
  z.lazy(() => LoadFindLink),
  z.array(z.lazy(() => LoadFindLink)),
])

export const LoadRead = z.record(
  z.union([z.boolean(), z.lazy(() => LoadReadLink)]),
)

export const LoadSave = z.record(
  z.union(
    z.array(z.lazy(() => LoadSaveBase)),
    z.lazy(() => LoadSaveBase),
  ),
)

export const LoadFindBind = z.object({
  form: z.enum(['bind']),
  list: z.array(z.lazy(() => LoadFindLink)),
})

export const LoadFindRoll = z.object({
  form: z.enum(['roll']),
  list: z.lazy(() => z.array(LoadFindLink)),
})

export const LoadFindTest = z.enum([
  'bond',
  'base_link_mark',
  'head_link_mark',
  'base_mark',
  'head_mark',
  'base_text',
  'miss_bond',
  'have_bond',
  'have_text',
])

export const LoadFindLike = z.object({
  base: z.lazy(() => LoadFindLikeLinkBond),
  form: z.enum(['like']),
  head: z.union([
    z.lazy(() => LoadFindLikeLinkBond),
    z.lazy(() => LoadFindLikeBond),
  ]),
  test: LoadFindTest,
})

export const LoadFindLink = z.union([
  z.lazy(() => LoadFindLike),
  z.lazy(() => LoadFindRoll),
  z.lazy(() => LoadFindBind),
])

export const LoadFindLikeBond = z.union([
  z.string(),
  z.boolean(),
  z.null(),
  z.number(),
])

export const LoadFindLikeLinkBond = z.object({
  link: z.string(),
})

export const LoadReadLink = z.object({
  find: z.optional(LoadFind),
  read: LoadRead,
})

export const LoadReadLink = z.object({
  find: z.optional(LoadFind),
  read: LoadRead,
})

export const LoadSaveBase = z.object({
  find: z.optional(z.lazy(() => LoadFind)),
  read: z.optional(z.lazy(() => LoadRead)),
  save: z.optional(z.lazy(() => LoadSave)),
  task: z.optional(z.string()),
})

export const LoadSort = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  tilt: z.enum(['+', '-']),
})
```

Comment: Normally in zod you infer the types from the values and create a parser/validator. In the case of recursive (or in your case mutually recursive) types you can't do that: you have to *define the types* like `type LoadFindLink = typeof LoadFindLike | typeof LoadFindRoll` and then annotate the zod construct `const LoadFindLink: z.ZodType<LoadFindLink> = z.lazy(...` to get a parser. I however can't seem to get your types to work even with this workaround.

Comment: @JaredSmith how far did you get? Maybe I could go off your example. I had this initially as a bunch of types [like here](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/58757be955af2fedb23bff07ff7bca85), so I am just trying to port it over to zod so I can take a JSON object and verify it matches (i.e. "parse" it).

Comment: I got to here along with that type in my earlier comment but it doesn't work: `const LoadFindLink: z.ZodType<LoadFindLink> = z.lazy(() => z.union([LoadFindLike, LoadFindRoll]));`. It also doesn't work if I take out the union from the type and the zod declaration and just make it an alias for `LoadFindLike` which isn't recursive.

Comment: @JaredSmith thank you! I got all but one working here: https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/da5ed3a5207e51d4115e5c02a58b4ab6 This one is failing: `z.array(z.lazy(() => LoadSaveBase))`.

Comment: I guess you can't use union inside a record, alright it all works, thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253746/discussion-between-lance-and-jared-smith).